# socket_recv receiving only 1448 bytes?

Tags: php, sockets

I´m having some problems with `socket_recv` to receiving the full data that my client sends to server, the code thats receive data is below:

```
while(true) {

      $changedSockets = $this->sockets;
      $result = socket_select($changedSockets,$write,$except,0);

      foreach($changedSockets as $socket){

          $buffer = '';
          $message = '';

          $bytes = @socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 4096, 0);


              echo "Lenght: (".$bytes.length.")";


            if ($bytes === false) {
            $error = self::getLastError( $this->socket );
            trigger_error( 'Failed to receive data from client #'.$client->id.': '.$error->message.' ['.$error->code.']', E_USER_WARNING );
            continue;
            }

          $len = ord( $buffer[1] ) & 127;

          $masks = null;
          $data = null;

                    if ( $len === 126 ) {
                        $masks = substr( $buffer, 4, 4 );
                        $data = substr( $buffer, 8 );
                    }
          elseif ( $len === 127 ) {
                        $masks = substr( $buffer, 10, 4 );
                        $data = substr( $buffer, 14 );
                    }
          else {
                        $masks = substr( $buffer, 2, 4 );
                        $data = substr( $buffer, 6 );
                    }

                    for( $index = 0; $index < strlen( $data ); $index++ ) {
                        $message .= $data[$index] ^ $masks[$index % 4];
                    }

                    if ( $bytes == 0 ) {
                        $this->disconnectClient( $socket );
                    }   

        }
        }
        }
```

This code works very well, but with one problem: If I send a text that exceeds the 5800 character, my code does not receive the full text (only a small part of it).

To see whats is happening I just insert the code below to see how many bytes has comes:

```
$bytes = @socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 4096, 0);
echo "Lenght: (".$bytes.length.")";
```

With this I notice that when you send a text smaller than 5800 characters the size of the bytes is the same size of bytes that the client sends,now when a text exceeds 5800 characters, the lenght of `socket_recv` stay on 1448 characters. **(if I change the value 4096 to a value higher it gets more characters, but if I turn up the php makes a memory problem)**

To solve this problem I try many things like using: `MSG_DONTWAIT`, `MSG_WAITALL`, `while($bytes > 0){ ... }`. But they all go into an infinite loop in a way that the rest of the code (below socket_recv) no longer runs.

How can I solve this problem? (I´m testing in wampserver in my localhost)

> Possible Solution

While I was racking my brain to solve this problem, I thought about a temporary solution:

> If we can not send a text larger than 5800 characters, I can try to
>   make in client side a code to cut the characters into smaller pieces than 5800
>   characters and send these parts separately to the socket with a
>   parameter that says that this entry is truncated, and inside the socket I
>   can try to filter them and join the characters.

Comment: You appear to be implementing a websocket server. Are you sure you want to do this from scratch, without much knowledge about how plain sockets work? You have to parse messages and continue to `recv()` until you obtained the entire message.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I try my ideia posted as an answer below and works very well and now my code can receive messages longer than 5800 characters.

Comment: @RyanVincent I know theses libraries, but has a little problem, many of libraries have things that I´ll not use, and as I'm trying to create a PRIVATE chat application and I´m always had curiosity about sockets...nothing better than to venture from scratch :D

Comment: The 'learning' approach I totally agree with. :) there is nothing like coding it to find out what really happens. Still, it is nice to know that are libraries that work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I realized many tests during that time, I realized a few things.

**Messages are received encrypted**

The messages when they are received on the server they are encrypted in standard [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2), if you run an `echo` in the variable `$buffer` you'll see things like: `×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)`,`Ó[ÁhÒß`...Example:

> For string `stackoverflow` you´ll see `iuj87xz`, if you insert that string again you´ll see a different hash, but they follow an encryption standard, example: for string `stack stack` I´ll se the same hash for both (`rrtfgh` and `rrtfgh`), but If I send again to socket I´ll see a diferente hash from before, but the hash will be the same for both (`mmjsht` and `mmjsht`).

**Messages are receiving in blocks**

When I show the `$buffer` on my screen and send a text with more than 10000 characters, I see that the `foreach($changedSockets as $socket)` It continued to be called until all parts of the messages were delivered.

If you see my code, you will see that each new message that comes is decrypted. But I had a problem, the first block messages that were decrypted I could read it clearly (read the text I had sent to the socket), but this does not happen with the other blocks that's comes.

Analyzing the hash contained in the variable `$buffer`I could notice something different in the first block, example: Lets send this text to the server: `Hello Hello Hello....(repeated 10000X)`

> Block 1:  `þ@¨¿7ÀlÓ[Ç)×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)`

> Block 2:  `×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)×RÄeÐÀlÓ[Ç)×RÄeÐÀlÓ`

> Block 1 Decrypted: `Hello Hello Hello Hello...`

> Block 2 Decrypted: `LLE LLE LLE LLE LLE...`

Notice the difference? It looks like I got a different entry code inside block 1 that does not exists in other blocks. It reminded me of images converted into base64 which has a boot code before the hash: `data:image/png;base64,......` and not works having a part of the hash without the boot code because this does not work (as we have seen above).

**Possible solution**

I can send the message to the socket with the length of that message like this: `"16049" Hello Hello Hello....` in server side I'd take this amount and divide it by `4096` that is the length of my `Socket_Recv`, with that I would have the result equal to 4, that would be the number of repetitions that I have to make up to receive all the blocks of the complete message.

Then I would not run the code to decrypt the message until I received the last block (meanwhile I'm taking the hash and concatenating inside `$buffer`).

I have not tested this code, it seems that's the way, after I finish testing the code I´ll back here to post the full code.